Powershell insert CR in massive array
I have a massive array of string characters that I would like to insert a carriage return every 10 characters.
For example, if my string array in Powershell is:
all_str_data = 02492340AF839e952DAB034B3D6DFCD029485DACCAEEFF...

I'd like the output to be:
all_str_data = 
02492340AF
839e952DAB
034B3D6DFC
D029485DAC
CAEEFF...

I'm eventually writing this to a file that I can use for a later step. Can someone help me here?
I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to Powershell. I haven't tried much yet and would love any additional help.

Define "massive". A few thousands? Okay, that's one option. A few billions? We might suggest something else.

One option can be to use -replace operator with regex, see https://regex101.com/r/6AoFuq/2 for details.
$all_str_data = '02492340AF839e952DAB034B3D6DFCD029485DACCAEEFF...'
$all_str_data -replace '(?<=\G.{10})(?!$)', "`r`n"

If you want a string array instead of a single multi-line string you can use the same regex but with -split:
$all_str_data -split '(?<=\G.{10})(?!$)'


Works like a champ folks. Thanks so much for your help!
The max this will be is on the order of a few million characters.

A solution without lookbehind assertion: https://regex101.com/r/Jw6lDP/1
